# Adding a Shared folder also as Document Root

Tags: apache, linux-mint, document-root

I am running Apache 2.4.41 on Linux Mint 20.
My document root is home/www/.
I have a laptop also connected using Samba.
I would like to add a shared folder also (from the laptop) to the Document Root settings.

How do I do it without removing home/www/?

Comment: `alias` could be used for that.

Comment: Thanks.
I tried with

    Alias /wwwpc file://192.168.xxx.xxx/home/mypc/www
in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf.
But trying to access the www folder on other pc using localhost/wwwpc gave me a 

**Forbidden**
You don't have permission to access this resource.
error. 
What might I be doing wrong.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. On your laptop, enable sharing of a folder.  Lets say `C:\LinuxShare`.
2. On mint, install Samba to mount that folder.  Mount it on `/mnt/LinuxShare`.

When that works...

3. Identify the user running your Apache.  You can start is and do `ps -ef | grep httpd`, it will show you the user.  Or look in httpd.conf, directive `User`.
4. Configure the permissions on `/mnt/LinuxShare` so that the user identified in 3) can read files under that directory.  You could use a group, or others permissions (for home it's ok, for corporate network, do not use others!).

When you have validated that the Apache user can read files under `/mnt/LinuxShare`

5. In your `VirtualHost`, add `Alias /wwwpc /mnt/LinuxShare`
6. Also add a `<Directory /mnt/LinuxShare>` section to allow reading that directory.

Restart Apache

7. on the laptop, put an HTML file (lets say SOMEPAGE.html) in `C:\LinuxShare`.  Make sure you can see it on mint under `/mnt/LinuxShare`.
8. on mint, start a browser and try `http://localhost/wwwpc/SOMEPAGE.html`.  You should see the page.
9. on the laptop, start a browser and try `http://THE_IP_OF_THE_MINT/wwwpc/SOMEPAGE.html`.  Remember that Apache runs on mint, so on the laptop you cannot access it via localhost.

Comment: Apologies, got tied up with work. Thanks a lot for your answer.. Will try it and get back.